# Как добавить ссылку с изображения javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который меняет изображение на другое при клике по нужной ссылке.

Как в этом коде добавить, что бы при клике на само изображение можно было переходить по определенной ссылке? У каждого изображения своя ссылка для перехода.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function l_image (a) {
    document.example_img.src = a;
}
</script>
```

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
 <td style="width: 50%;">
  <a href="javascript:l_image('image/img_1.png')">Ссылка на изображение № 1</a><br>
  <a href="javascript:l_image('image/img_2.png')">Ссылка на изображение № 2</a><br>
  <a href="javascript:l_image('image/img_3.png')">Ссылка на изображение № 3</a><br>
  <a href="javascript:l_image('image/img_4.png')">Ссылка на изображение № 4</a><br>
 </td>
 <td style="width: 50%;">
  <img src="image/img_1.png" name="example_img"
  alt="Картинки для демонстрации работы скрипта смены изображений">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Оберните ваш img в тег a и меняйте там атрибут htef на нужный или событие клика прикрутите к img. Где в предоставленном коде лежит сама ссылка, на которую должен перейти пользователь при клике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже Вам [подсказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562153/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-javascript#comment2813567_1562153) SwaD, необходимо просто поместить тег изображения в ссылку и также менять её атрибут в обработчике события.
Также советую Вам не не смешивать разметку и JavaScript.
Ниже в примере используются data-аттрибуты, т.к. Вы не пояснили где находится информация об используемой ссылке:

```js
let $image = document.getElementById( 'image' ),
    $image_wrapper = document.getElementById( 'image_wrapper' );

document.querySelectorAll( '.image-btn' ).forEach( a => {
  a.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
    // отменяем поведение по-умолчанию (переход по ссылке)
    e.preventDefault();
    $image.src = a.href;
    $image_wrapper.href = a.dataset.link;
  });
});
```

```css
.image-btn {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 10px monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100"
     data-link="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300"
     class="image-btn">Изображение 1</a>
  <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100"
     data-link="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300"
     class="image-btn">Изображение 2</a>
  <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/3/100/100"
     data-link="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300"
     class="image-btn">Изображение 3</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" id="image_wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100"
         name="example_img"
         id="image"
         alt="Изображение для демонстрации работы скрипта" />
  </a>
</p>
```